# Stop focus being lost when a grid or border control is touched in Win RT Xaml

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, focus, winrt-xaml

I have a grid and in Row 1 I have a stack panel with 2 textboxes. The textboxes highlight when they have focus (I use a custom style to do this but the same happens without one).

When I click on MyButton the button event fires and the focus stays within the textbox as I have IsTabStop="False" on the button. However if I click on the grid space next to the buttons the focus on the textbox is lost. How can I stop this happening on controls like the grid as there is no IsTabStop option on the grid?. I have the same problems on other controls. Any idea how I can stop focus being lost when a grid for example is touched?

This is a Windows 8 store app using WIN RT XAML and is designed for use on a tablet device.

Thanks

```
<Grid Background="LightGray"
      x:Name="gridMainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Header -->
    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Background="White"
            Margin="5">

    </Border>

    <!-- Details -->        
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Height="100" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Height="100" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            Background="white" 
            Margin="5">
        <Grid x:Name="gridButton"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="MyButton" 
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    MinHeight="80"
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">My Button</TextBlock>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="buttonEquipment" Grid.Column="3"
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    MinHeight="80"
                    Click="buttonEquipment_Click">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Equipment</TextBlock>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ill give a work around for this. Just give a try and let me know if it works.

use this link and implement the mouse up and shift focus to the testbox

[Mouse gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

try it out and keep a note of side effect. Do something like txtBoxaEx.focus() on mouse pointer up.